# How are nazir and sota connected?

Tags: translation, sotah-secluded-woman, artscroll, nozir, maseches-nazir

The *gemara* Nazir 2a quotes a *baraisa* saying that

> כל הרואה סוטה בקלקולה **יזיר** עצמו מן היין
>
> Anyone who sees a *sota* in her disgrace (**would**/**should**) swear off wine.

The word יזיר, as I understand it could just as well express "would swear off..." or "should swear off..." Artscroll indicates the grammatical mode of this line, quoted in Rash"i's commentary on *B'midbar* 6:2, as "should". It is also translated as such in the opening lines of the Artscroll *g'mara* in both *masechtos Nazir* and *Sota*. However, one footnote in Artscroll's elucidation on *Nazir* 2 takes for granted that it means "would want to..."

Is the quoted *baraisa* giving a **prescription** to those who witness the unfortunate plight of the *sota* or is it **describing** the instinctive reaction one is likely to have upon seeing the same?

<sub>NOTE: I always understood it as "would", as that would fit with the fact that this is quoted as an answer to the question "why are these topics juxtaposed?" I see now that "should" would fit almost as well, but I am not convinced and I'm really not sure how to prove one way or the other without external evidence.</sub>

Comment: The word "Yazir" has the root "zar" meaning "strange". The yod at the beginning is future tense in Hebrew. I'm not sure how Artscroll gets the meaning "swear off". I have to look at Rashi's explanation further to get a better sense of how "swearing" emanates from the shoresh (root) of "zar".

Comment: To clarify, I made up "swear off". The question is only about the mode of the imperfect י in this case, not the lexical value of the root ז.ר.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for that clarification. Still have to research.

Comment: @DanF That's not the Shoresh. It's N.Z.R. The N drops off in Hifil and becomes a Dagesh in the Z.

Comment: @DoubleAA - thanks for the correction. "Modern" shorashim are 3 (occasionally 4) letters. Rashi often mentions 2-letter shorashim (don't know if he does in this pasuk about nazir.) I'm uncertain where Rashi got the 2-letter shoresh from. It's possible that Hebrew shoresh forms have changed since then.

Comment: From Rashi to [Iyov 1:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16403#showrashi=true&v=5): _So would Job do: Heb. יעשה, lit. will do. He would always do in this manner. When Scripture writes about a constant occurrence, sometimes it writes in the past tense, and sometimes in the future tense._ -- Perhaps the same thing applies here. It uses future tense, but means constantly.

Comment: @DanF is it possible yazir here is aramaic and the zayin is functioning in place of a daled as we commonly find dahav in place of zahav and other such cases?

Comment: @user6591 - I'm not sure where you have seen the word dahav used in Tana"ch. Can you give an example? Offhand, the only Aramaic words I know of in the Torah all refer to geographic places. If you know of an Aramaic verb in the Torah, let me know. Menachem's analysis is correct, as this format is used in a number of places in the Torah as well as the rest of Tana"ch.

Comment: @DanF There are certainly roots that are both Hebrew and Aramaic that appear in Tana"ch.

Comment: @WAF - Yes. I just recalled that "hava" meaning "give" is related to the Aramaic "hav".

Comment: @DanF, I wasn't referring to the word nazir in the torah, i was referring to the word yazir in the braisa. And although its a stretch to assume we are discussing a nazir and chazzal decided to cutely use the similar word yazir but really meant nedder, i can defend the idea by pointing out that the passuk itself closely associated the word nedder and nazir.

Comment: @WAF - "i can defend the idea by pointing out that the passuk itself closely associated the word nedder and nazir" - Excellent point, here. Something to look at. Can you refer me to the specific pasuk that makes you think this? I THINK I know what your gettig at, but the pasuk would confirm it.

Comment: במדבר ו ב 'איש או אשה כי יפלא לנדר נדר נזיר להזיר לה'. Seems it's a specific type of nedder called nezirus

Answer (score 4):

*Tol'dos Yitzchak* (by Rabbi *Yitzchak* Karo, uncle of the *Bes Yosef*) [has two explanations](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40261&pgnum=121):

> "to tell you whoever sees a *sota* in her detriment…": its explanation is as a way of a command: he's obliged to swear off of wine, in his seeing her death due to the drinking of wine….
>
> And it is also natural: … "whoever sees a *sota* in her detriment…": that when he sees such great filth — a thigh falling in the street, a belly swelling, her body in pieces — the desire for women will be annulled in him and he will, of his own accord, swear off of wine when he sees that it is a bottle full of excrement….

*Tora T'mima* ([*Bamidbar* 6:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14018&pgnum=61)) explains the *g'mara* as meaning that

> …and when they heard the detriment that comes through wine, many would swear off of wine….

And there's a story in *Otzar Chayim* (compiled by Rabbi *Chayim Yaakov* Zuckerman; at *Bamidbar* 6:2) in which Rabbi *David* Forkes (a student of the *Baal Shem Tov*) understood it as prescriptive.